# Stacking multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape, tidyr

I am trying to convert data frame into long-form in R. 
This is an example data for surveys conducted in 'id' grids over 9 days and if the variable of interest was detected '1' or not detected '0'. 
I want to convert this data frame so that the number of surveys is reduced from 9 to 3 
but each survey period now contains 3 visits. 
I am trying to do so by stacking three columns at a time, so that survey visits 'v1' to 'v9' (in the image below) gets converted to v1, v2, v3 by adding a column called 'visit_no' which describe the visit number within the survey period.
The following link is the image of dataframe in current form and below if the code to generate the data

[image]

Code to generate data:

```
id<- c(240,220,160)
v1<- c(rep(0,9))
v2<-c(rep(0,3),1,rep(0,5))
v3<- c(1,rep(0,8))

v<-as.data.frame(rbind(v1,v2,v3))

survey<- cbind(id,v)
survey
```

This is the link to the image of data frame I need

Reference data-frame

[image]

Comment: Your code to generate the survey data doesn't match the posted images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using `reshape` in **base R**"

```
reshape(survey, direction="long", idvar="id",
        varying=list(c("V1","V4","V7"), c("V2","V5","V8"), c("V3","V6","V9")),
        v.names=c("Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit3"), timevar="visit_no") 

       id visit_no Visit1 Visit2 Visit3
240.1 240        1      0      0      0
220.1 220        1      0      0      0
160.1 160        1      1      0      0
240.2 240        2      0      0      0
220.2 220        2      1      0      0
160.2 160        2      0      0      0
240.3 240        3      0      0      0
220.3 220        3      0      0      0
160.3 160        3      0      0      0
```

---

If you want it sorted by id, then add `arrange` from dplyr

```
 %>% dplyr::arrange(id)

   id visit_no Visit1 Visit2 Visit3
1 160        1      1      0      0
2 160        2      0      0      0
3 160        3      0      0      0
4 220        1      0      0      0
5 220        2      1      0      0
6 220        3      0      0      0
7 240        1      0      0      0
8 240        2      0      0      0
9 240        3      0      0      0
```

---

If your original variable names were in a consistent format, then the reshape command is even simpler because it will correctly guess the times from the names. For example,

```
names(survey)[2:10] <- paste0(names(survey)[2:10], ".", rep(1:3, 3))
head(survey)
        id V1.1 V2.2 V3.3 V4.1 V5.2 V6.3 V7.1 V8.2 V9.3
v1 240    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
v2 220    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
v3 160    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

reshape(survey, direction="long", idvar="id",
        varying=2:10, # Can just give the indices now.
        v.names=c("Visit1", "Visit2", "Visit3"), timevar="visit_no") %>%
  arrange(id)
```

---

Although the times are in a consistent format, the original **variable names** are not, so R cannot guess the names for the long format (Visit1, Visit2, Visit3), and these need to be supplied in the `v.names` argument.

If they *were* in a consistent format, then the reshape is even simpler.

```
names(survey)[2:10] <- paste0("Visit", rep(1:3, each=3), ".", rep(1:3, 3))
head(survey)    
    id Visit1.1 Visit1.2 Visit1.3 Visit2.1 Visit2.2 Visit2.3 Visit3.1 Visit3.2 Visit3.3
v1 240        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
v2 220        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0
v3 160        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0

reshape(survey, direction="long", varying=2:10, timevar="visit_no") %>%
  arrange(id)
```

---

The **tidyr** version would probably involve two reshapes; one to get everything in very long form, and again to get it back to a wider form (what I call the 1 step back, 2 steps forward method).

Comment: Thanks! My example was a simplified version of the data, the solution worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the columns based on the sequence that you want.

```
names(survey)[-1] <- paste(rep(paste0("visit", 1:3), each =3), 1:3, sep = "_")

names(survey)
#[1] "id"  "visit1_1" "visit1_2" "visit1_3" "visit2_1" "visit2_2" "visit2_3" 
#    "visit3_1" "visit3_2" "visit3_3"
```

And then use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to get data in different columns.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(survey, cols = -id, names_to = c(".value", "visit_no"),
                    names_sep = "_") %>%
       type.convert(as.is = TRUE)


# A tibble: 9 x 5
#     id visit_no visit1 visit2 visit3
#  <int>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1   240        1      0      0      0
#2   240        2      0      0      0
#3   240        3      0      0      0
#4   220        1      0      1      0
#5   220        2      0      0      0
#6   220        3      0      0      0
#7   160        1      1      0      0
#8   160        2      0      0      0
#9   160        3      0      0      0
```